# URL rewriting - Ember Routes to URL On Apache Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ember.js, web-applications

I have deployed my ember app in Apache Tomcat version 9.

The index page works fine `localhost:8080/myemberapp/`
but when i try to access `localhost:8080/myemberapp/login` it returns `404 error`.

I also Read about URL rewriting and added the following code snippet to `.htaccess` file

```
#html5 pushstate (history) support:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And added the following to tomcat `conf/context.xml` file

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />`

But still I cannot access any other ember routes after deploying in Apache Tomcat.

Can anybody solve this so that, each routes in the ember app can be mapped to a custom URL.

Comment: "it does not work" isn't quite enough to provide an answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question with appropriate information, otherwise you risk it to be closed

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/tutorial/deploying/#toc_servers)? Basically your server must always return the `index.html` with `200 OK` instead of your `404` page, so when a path is not found it should fall back to the `index.html`.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this, actually after placing code in the .htaccess file it only shows the index page but when i try to use any other routes in the ember app in returns 404 error.

Comment: @OlafKock I took your advice and added some more information, Please Help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this problem when I deployed my ember app in Github GH pages.
What is the problem here is when you access `localhost:8080/myemberapp/login` route your server would look for index.html in login route or login.html file.

So In order to overcome this you'd need to mention that all routes that come after `myemberapp` are `virtual routes`, In order to mention that you'd need to change `locationType` property's value to `hash` in `config/environment.js` file of your Ember app [Ex](https://github.com/imkathir/FarmersMarket/blob/master/config/environment.js).

When `locationType` property's value is `hash`, `#` symbol will be inserted to your app's url, so your app's url would change to `localhost:8080/myemberapp#/login`
[Refernce](https://medium.com/@theenadayalan/what-locationtype-property-does-in-emberjs-application-d6e790cdf7de)

[Example Ember app's repo](https://github.com/imkathir/FarmersMarket) and you can view that app [here](https://imkathir.github.io/FarmersMarket/#/dupfinder)